# ORA-02270 error

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys

I tried to create a table with a foreign key to another one but I don't know why this error

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

keeps popping up every time I try, please help me

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    username VARCHAR2(100),
    cedula VARCHAR2(100),
    ultimoAcceso DATE,
    CONSTRAINT Pk PRIMARY KEY (cedula,username)
    ) ;

CREATE TABLE pagoPlanillas(
    ced VARCHAR2(100),
    fecha DATE,
    detalle VARCHAR2(100),
    salario VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY(ced) REFERENCES usuarios(cedula)
    ) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key on table `usuarios` is a compound key made up of `cedula` and `username`. Your foreign key constraint requires an index on `cedula` alone. Just create another index.

Comment: thanks it worked! =) here's what i did:

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
 username VARCHAR2(100),
 cedula VARCHAR2(100),
 ultimoAcceso DATE,
 CONSTRAINT Pk PRIMARY KEY (cedula)
 ) ;
       
CREATE TABLE pagoPlanillas(
 ced VARCHAR2(100),
 fecha DATE,
 detalle VARCHAR2(100),
 salario VARCHAR2(100),
 CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY(ced) REFERENCES usuarios(cedula)
 ) ;

Answer (score 1):

(cedula,username)  is a compound key. By combining, this two columns, you are making primary key in the table "Usuarios". And if you refer only one column  in the table pagoplanillas, then You will get this error. Since, cedula columns alone may contain duplicate value and not a primary key

Comment: thanks it worked! =) here's what i did

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
 username VARCHAR2(100),
 cedula VARCHAR2(100),
 ultimoAcceso DATE,
 CONSTRAINT Pk PRIMARY KEY (cedula)
 ) ;
       
CREATE TABLE pagoPlanillas(
 ced VARCHAR2(100),
 fecha DATE,
 detalle VARCHAR2(100),
 salario VARCHAR2(100),
 CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY(ced) REFERENCES usuarios(cedula)
 ) ;

Comment: dont allow me .in 6 minutes i'll do it